# How to display thumbnails of uploaded images with ASP .NET AjaxFileUploader

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, thumbnails

I am using ASP .Net AJAX FILE UPLOAD in my website. It is working fine.

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ThrobberID="myThrobber" ContextKeys="fred"
                        AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" MaximumNumberOfFiles="5" runat="server" />
```

I want to display the thumbnails of uploaded images withuot postback.

as shown in http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

How can i do it with ajax?